# How do I set a proper .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to setup a proper .htaccess file, and what I mean by this is I am trying to setup the .htaccess to do:

- Have `http://website.com/members.php` read like `http://website.com/members/`
- Have `http://website.com/index.php` to read like `http://website.com` with or without /
- Set default recommended image/website file expire dates
- Gzip website

... and anything else that is recommended.

edit: this is what I currently have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$  profile.php?id=$1  [L]

# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>

# BEGIN Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END Rewrite
```

Comment: What have you managed to get so far?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: a proper .htaccess file is one that doesn't exist. they should be used for temporary overrides. if you have access to the httpd.conf-level stuff, you should put your directives there. .htaccess is highly inefficient on production systems.

Comment: I feel like this question could be a lot more useful if you split it up, although I'm pretty sure we have already [covered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6520671/35070) [all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2676744/35070) [points](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5846376/35070).

Comment: [Here is a great little tutorial that I used.](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Comment: a .htaccess that doesn't exist? But then what is its purpose. And how else would I be able to make members.php read like members without putting it into a whole new folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file to form the website.com/user sort of links:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /members/profile.php?username=$1
```

And also for better explanations follow the User Profile videos under Register and Login series by PHPAcademy

[User Profile Link Formation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrc4p-J_x9s)

There are other parts too. You can see them yourself.

And about your other queries, others will help you out because I can't help you completely.

Comment: The last line of the code. If your profile page is in the members directory, then add that directory followed by the file, username corresponds to the username field which you have set for yourself. $1 tells to overwrite and display the php page as user link.

Comment: Thanks but I wrote it already like this: RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)$  profile.php?id=$1  [L]